# Unique Faces in 6 Rolls of a Fair Die

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Roll a die 6 times and let X be the number of different numbers that are represented. For example, if you get 1,6,3,5,3,5 then X equal to 4 since 1,3,5 and 6 are represented. what is expectation of x.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  use indicator variables (one for each possible value).

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** Here is a simulation of ten million of your 6-roll experiments. Maybe it will
help you get a correct combinatorial solution.
The answer should be correct to at least three of significant digits.

```
 m = 10^7; x = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {sam
   roll = sample(1:6, 6, repl=T)
   x[i] = length(unique(roll)) }
 mean(x)
 ## 3.990658

 table(x)/m
 x
 ##         1         2         3         4         5         6 
 ## 0.0001257 0.0199736 0.2313567 0.5016234 0.2315020 0.0154186 

 factorial(6)/6^6
 ## 0.0154321
```

Below is a histogram of the simulated distribution of $X$. 
The probability $P(X=1)$ is too small to show at the
resolution of the plot. 
It should be trivial to find $P(X=1)$
and $P(X = 6).$ Several of the 'Related' items shown in
the list to the right are relevant to finding the distribution
of $X,$ including $P(X = 2)$ and $P(X = 3).$

[image]

*Note 1:* In several simulations like the one above, the answer was
always slightly below 4, so it does not seem likely that $E(X)$ is
*exactly* 4.

**Answer** (a day later): However, It is not necessary to know the distribution of
$X$ in order to find $E(X).$ Following @lulu's clever hint, we can
define six indicator random variables $U_i,$ for $i = 1, \dots, 6.$
Let $U_i$ be $1$ if face $i$ appears at least once, and $0$ otherwise.
Then $$E(X) = E(U_1 +  U_2 + \dots + U_6) = \sum_i E(U_i).$$ 
The $U_i$ are not even close to being independent, but they all
have the same distribution with $E(U_i) = P(U_i = 1) = (1 - (5/6)^6),$ and the equation above for $E(X)$
does not require independence. Hence, $E(X) = 6(1-(5/6)^6) =  3.990612,$
in good agreement with the simulated value.

*Note 2:* $Cor(U_1, U_2) \approx -.11.$ Because the $U_i$ are correlated
it is *not* true that $Var(X) = \sum_i Var(U_i).$ From simulation,
$Var(X) \approx 0.605.$